# Integral of an odd function

Tags: real-analysis

For an odd function $f$ the integral $\int_{-R}^R f dx$ vanishes if $f$ is continuous on $[-R,+R]$. Now, let $f(x)=\frac{\cos(x)}{x}$ which is odd but discontinuous at 0. How can I show (not) that $\int_{-R}^R f dx = 0$?

Comment: The integral is improper. To compute it, you need to compute $\lim_{t\to 0^-}\int_{R}^tf(x)\,dx$ and $\lim_{t\to 0^+}\int _t^Rf(x)\,dx$. Only if both limits exist will the improper Riemann integral exist and equal their sum. However, I *think* that $\int_0^1\frac{\cos x}{x}\,dx$ does not converge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that $f$ is not merely discontinuous at $0$ but **unbounded** near $0$.  Thus what you have is an improper integral.  In order for it to converge, by definition, you need $\lim_{a \rightarrow 0^+} \int_a^R f$ to exist.

But this limit does not exist.  **Hint**: for $x$ close to zero, $\frac{ \cos x}{x}$ is close to $\frac{1}{x}$.

**Added** Of course you also need $\lim_{a \rightarrow 0^-} \int_{-R}^a f$ to exist.  But on the one hand, the oddness tells you that if the first limit exists then so will the second.  On the other hand, the first limit does not exist, which is enough to show the divergence.)

Answer (score 2):

Your function is unbounded near $0$, in fact $f(x) \approx 1/x$ for small $x$. (By a Maclaurin expansion of $\cos x$.) Hence, your improper integral diverges.

Answer (score 1):

For $-\frac{\pi}{4}\le x\le\frac{\pi}{4}$, we have $\left|\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\right|\ge\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}|x|}$. Therefore, as $\epsilon\to0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_\epsilon^{\pi/4}\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x
&\ge\int_\epsilon^{\pi/4}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\,x}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\log\left(\frac{\pi}{4\epsilon}\right)\\
&\to\infty\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi/4}^{-\epsilon}\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x
&\le\int_{-\pi/4}^{-\epsilon}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\,x}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\log\left(\frac{\pi}{4\epsilon}\right)\\
&\to-\infty\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}
$$
diverges.

**Cauchy Principal Value**

Note that the 
$$
\int_{-R}^{-\epsilon}\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x+\int_{\epsilon}^{R}\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x=0\tag{4}
$$
as $\epsilon\to0$. Equation $(4)$ says that the [Cauchy Principal Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) of 
$$
\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x=0\tag{5}
$$